# Isomorphism type of the group generated by permutations $x$ and $y$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is an extract from an abstract algebra past paper, I don't really understand the question? I know about permutations, and disjoint cycles, and the other parts of the question(not included), I have found straightforward, however this is a myth to me!

Say the permutations $x$ and $y$ are given by:

$x=(1,6)(2,5)(3,4)$

$y= (1)(2,6)(3,5)(4)$.

State the Isomorphism type of the group generated by $x$ and $y$.

Thanks!!

Comment: Let $G$ be the group generated by $x$ and $y$. How many elements has $G$? To which group of this order is it isomorphic? Start with an easier example, say, with $x=(12)$ and $y=(123)$ in $S_3$.

Comment: If it's "isomorphism type" that bothers you, I think you're being asked to find the common name for the generated group - e.g. Klein four group, $S_3$, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the dihedral group $D_{12}$ of order $12$.

The symmetry group of a regular hexagon with vertex set $\{1,2,\ldots,6\}$ is generated by a reflection $y$ about an axis through a vertex and the center of the hexagon and a rotation $r = (1,2,3,4,5,6)$.  This symmetry group is called the dihedral group of order $12$.

It can be seen that applying the reflection $x$ followed by reflection $y$ gives the rotation. Therefore, $x$ and $y$ together generate exactly $D_{12}$.

The following SAGE code can be entered at https://sagecell.sagemath.org/ and gives the output "D6" (which is the notation for my $D_{12}$:

```
x = PermutationGroupElement('(1,6)(2,5)(3,4)')
y = PermutationGroupElement('(2,6)(3,5)')
G = PermutationGroup([x,y])
G.structure_description()
```